# How to report interest on uncashed savings bonds?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, interest, form-1040, savings-bonds

I have a Series EE U.S. savings bond that matured in 2018, but I still haven't redeemed it.

What do I put for the payer's name on 2018 Schedule B (Form 1040), line 1?

More details:

IRS Publication 550 says that as an individual tax payer using the cash method of reporting income, I can report the interest on my Series EE US savings bond using method 1: "Postpone reporting the interest until the earlier of the year you cash or dispose of the bonds or the year in which they mature."

I have to file Schedule B (Form 1040) because I had over $1,500 of taxable interest.

Comment: If the interest was over $10, which I'd expect at maturity for even the minimum EE, they should have sent you (or provided for you to download) a form 1099-INT including the official payer name, address, and TIN (which I expect was _probably_ a Federal Reserve Bank acting as fiscal agent, because that's mostly how Treasury handles this type of thing, but I don't follow the Savings Bond program specifically).

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thank you for commenting. Yes, the interest was over $10. It's a paper bond. I didn't receive a 1099-INT. Any suggestions on what I should put for the payer's name?

Comment: (1) lazy way: just put US Savings Bond. If they do an automated match and the amount(s) are correct it probably won't even check the name(s); if a human ever looks at it, they'll know what you meant. (2) careful way: try to [get a wage-and-income transcript](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/transcript-types-and-ways-to-order-them). In the past the online app had very hard to pass authentication, although they claim they've improved it. The paper 4506T is probably backlogged, like all their paper processing due to COVID.

Comment: Thanks, @dave_thompson_085. I filed it on Monday. I just put "Matured uncashed U.S. savings bond".